# Self -Signed certificate vs CA

Tags: java, ssl, encryption

I am making a solution for encryption of files via combination of RSA and AES. RSA is basically used for handshaking here to encrypt the symmetric key and decrypt at the receiver end via key pairs.

I have used Java Keystores for Private keys and Self-Signed certificates for Public Keys. Both are created as below:

**KEY STORE**

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias BANK -keystore receiverKeystore.jks -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

**CERTIFICATE EXPORT**

```
keytool -export -alias BANK -keystore receiverKeystore.jks -rfc -file bankCert.cer
```

Similarly both are used in Java as below:

**Private Key**

```
private void setKeys() {

        KeyStore senderKeyStore = null;
        String keyStorePassword = "fms123";

        try {

            senderKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance( "JKS" );  
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream( keystorePath );
            senderKeyStore.load( is, keyStorePassword.toCharArray() );  

            senderPrivateKey = ( PrivateKey ) senderKeyStore.getKey( KEYSTORE_ALIAS, keyStorePassword.toCharArray() );

            receiverPublicKey = loadReceiverPublicKeyFromCertificate();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( " Exception in setting keys from key store = " + e );
        }

    }
```

**PUBLIC KEY**

```
private PublicKey loadReceiverPublicKeyFromCertificate () {

        PublicKey publicKey = null; 

        try {

            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream( certificateFilePath );
            CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance( "X.509" );
            X509Certificate certificate = ( X509Certificate ) factory.generateCertificate( fin );
            publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( " Exception in loading receiver certificate = " + e );
        }

        return publicKey;
    }
```

I have now following Questions:

1. Is the the correct way do it?
2. If I use a trusted certificate here, how will the public key will be fetched from it? Will it be fetched in the same way? and for private keys? will I use the same approach or something from the certificate?
3. How can I distribute my certificate to the receiver? whats the secure communication shall for that?

I am new to encryption, will be very glad to get some advises.

Comment: 1. Yes, but you can get the public key from the keystore, as shown in the Javadoc: just get the Certificate from the PrivateKeyEntry and get the public key from that. 2. Same way. 3. You need an ofline mechanism. You can't transport it over the mechanism it is intended to secure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you please tell me whether I should use CA or Self Signed?

Comment: If you have a good solution for (3) you can use self-signed, but a CA certificate removes this need.

Comment: Okay, lets say, I am going with a self signed certificate; so is my code fine to cater the solution i.e. fetching of keys?

Comment: You've left out critical details. You never mention ssl once in your question, it just appears as one of your tags. You begin with a summary of hybrid encryption. Does that mean you're not using SSL but instead writing your own custom security protocol? Another critical consideration is the nature of the client. Is the client software just a standard web browser? If so then you should use a commercial ca. If, on the other hand, your client is an app that you have written, then almost all the benefits of a using a commercial ca disappear and a self-signed cert is likely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. There are two utilities one at the sender end for encryption and other at the receiver end for decryption. both of them are developed by me. It means as per your explanation I can go with the self-signed certificate with above provided implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handshaking is called *key establishment*. Handshaking is used for (online) transport modes, and I don't think you're developing that. I'd use a PKCS#12 key store instead, JKS is kinda deprecated. The whole idea of using a `char[]` for the password is that you can delete its contents directly after using it, so using a `String` as input is not a good idea. Strings are usually *interned* and always *immutable* in Java, so you cannot destroy them without ugly hacks involving native code.

Trusted certificates are no different from untrusted certificates. Yes, you can retrieve the public key from it. The private keys are commonly stored together with the certificate chain leading to the leaf user certificate that the private key belongs to. However, the private key is **not part of** the certificate, and therefore you cannot retrieve a private key from it. That's OK though, private keys should be established on the location where they are needed; there is no need to transport them other than for backup purposes.

How you can send the certificate to the receiver is up to you. The tricky part is to have the receiver trust the certificate. It's valid to use a pre-established key such as a trusted PGP key . If you haven't got such a key then you are in trouble though. What you can do is to use other methods to establish trust. Let the other party call you and then verify that the **certificate fingerprint** (basically just a hash over the certificate) is correct is probably one of the easiest ways. Bringing it over in person is of course also an option, if your users are not too far away.

You cannot create a secure channel out of thin air though. If you cannot trust who is on the other side, then establishing full trust is obviously impossible.

Comment: I am using keys from Keystores and self-signed certificate. Is this fine?

Comment: or I shall move to OpenPGP?

Comment: Yes, that's fine for small scale operations. You'd have to rely on a trusted third party for anything else. I'd choose between CMS and OpenPGP depending on the trust model, but in your case CMS seems the more logical option.

Comment: Can you explain CMS a bit please?

Comment: No, that's asking for a bit much, read the Wikipedia page or something. If you have questions there is always the crypto and IT security sites of stackexchange. Note that asking additional questions in the comments is not considered good practice, especially not if the original question has been sufficiently answered.

Comment: Alright, by the way your description was quite useful for me thanks alot.